# Does Delphi threadvar work for Parallel.For?

Tags: delphi

from [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ThreadVar) it says

> "The ThreadVar keyword starts a set of variable definitions that are
>   used by threads.    Each thread is given a separate instance of each
>   variable, thereby avoiding data conflicts, and preserving thread
>   independence. "

So can I use in Parallel.For like this?

```
threadvar
    threadID: integer;

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Tot: Integer;
begin
 TParallel.For(1, Max, procedure (I: Integer)
   begin
     threadID := i;  // each thread gets its own threadID?
     if IsPrime (threadID) then
       TInterlocked.Increment (Tot);
   end);
end;
```

Comment: yes you can :) :)

Comment: FWIW, these days it is idiomatic to use `AtomicIncrement` rather than `TInterlocked.Increment` because that is an intrinsic that gets expanded inline to efficient platform specific code.

Comment: TInterlocked.Increment is an inline function that expands to TInterlocked.Add, which then expands to AtomicIncrement, which as you say, expands to inline platform-specific machine code. In this case, TInterlocked.Increment will end up being the same thing.

Comment: So you may as well avoid stressing out the inline engine and go straight to the horses mouth. Plus it reads better.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure. Whatever floats your boat. My point was that TInterlocked.Increment is just as efficient. Your comment implied otherwise.

Comment: In your example you may as well use a local variable in the task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can certainly use `threadvar` with PPL code. Internally the PPL code stands on top of the system threading libraries, and so `threadvar` works as you would expect.

Comment: Technically, you're correct that threadvar will work fine with the threads within the threadpool used for TParallel.For. However, how the tasks are scheduled onto those threads is anything but predictable or stable. The threadvar may at any time disappear as threads in the threadpool are retired.

Comment: @Allen Which pretty much renders thread vars useless when working with a task based interface, right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think it's useless. You just need to initialize it at the start of each task.

Comment: @Allen I can't see how a thread would be pulled from under a task that is busy executing in that thread or am I misunderstanding your comment. It makes sense that a threadvar wouldn't carry between different tasks.

Comment: @Graymatter That is my point... why bother with a threadvar if it's not predictable across tasks?

Comment: @AllenBauer It still adds value. For example, you can preallocate a big block of working memory and initialize the threadvar to an offset in that memory. That's a bit of a silly example but I hope you get my point. As it stands, threadvar's are initialized for new threads so one would expect to have to do the same in a task. Another option is to use it as a list index of sorts for working objects/pools. This is very useful if your setup code for these things is expensive or requires a number of locks.

Comment: @Graymatter And when that thread is retired, how is that block of memory freed? If you create and control the thread, it's fairly simple. However, in the thread pool, the point is you don't control the lifetime of the threads and don't have the opportunity to free that memory.

Comment: @AllenBauer True, we do something similar but it doesn't use threadvar and works in a very controlled environment. While the threads come from a pool, they are initialized, and we release everything after processing. In the OP's case, it would make much more sense to just use a local variable.